# How to use TSPLIB in Matlab

Tags: matlab, import, traveling-salesman

Is there an easy way to import *.tsp files into Matlab? I have not been able to find existing solutions, but since TSPLIB is referred to so much, I expect that there must be an existing solution already.

Otherwise:
Would it be easier to pre-process the data using Java (with regex for example), or directly write in Matlab?

Edit:
it has been suggested to use the .xml files instead. However, the bigger instances are read very slowly. I am guessing this also has to do with the file being a lot bigger: for pcb3038 the .tsp file is about 100kb, while the .xml file is close to 500 mb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I found to do this in Matlab is opening the xml files using fopen(), and then read them line by line using fgetl().
In addition to that I used regexp() to interpret the lines and act accordingly.

This allowed me to read the +- 500mb xml file and put the relevant data in a distance matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in what structure original TSPLIB data files come, but according to the [TSBLIB website](https://www.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/groups/comopt/software/TSPLIB95/), TSPLIB data files are also available in [XML format](https://www.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/groups/comopt/software/TSPLIB95/XML-TSPLIB/instances/), for example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<travellingSalesmanProblemInstance>

  <name>a280</name>

  <source>TSPLIB</source>

  <description>drilling problem (Ludwig)</description>

  <doublePrecision>15</doublePrecision>

  <ignoredDigits>5</ignoredDigits>

  <graph>
    <vertex>
      <edge cost="2.000000000000000e+01">1</edge>
      <edge cost="2.408318915758459e+01">2</edge>
      <edge cost="3.298484500494128e+01">3</edge>
      <edge cost="3.298484500494128e+01">4</edge>
      <edge cost="4.275511665286390e+01">5</edge>
      <edge cost="5.571355310873648e+01">6</edge>
      ...
      <edge cost="4.560701700396552e+01">275</edge>
      <edge cost="3.492849839314596e+01">276</edge>
      <edge cost="2.912043955712207e+01">277</edge>
      <edge cost="2.039607805437114e+01">278</edge>
    </vertex>
  </graph>

</travellingSalesmanProblemInstance>
```

You can [import XML files](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/importing-xml-documents.html) using [`xmlread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xmlread.html), then parse them using the [example code](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xmlread.html#bsmo1ax-8) provided by MATLAB. Alternatively, you can try the [`xml2struct`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28518) utility from FEX. Lastly, if you prefer working with python, you can also use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) from within MATLAB using the python API (`py.bs4.BeautifulSoup(...)`).

Comment: Works great for smaller instances, but reading xml takes too much time for the bigger ones

Comment: @Bjorn Unfortunately, I am unfamiliar with TSPLIB completely. If you want some help, I'd suggest you provide some documentation of the structure of the non-xml TSPLIB files. I bet they shouldn't be too difficult to read either way. A quick search reveals [this python tool](https://github.com/tsartsaris/TSPLIB-python-parser), which should be callable from MATLAB.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will find out more about using python (in combination with Matlab)!